# Initialize NestJS project with TypeScript without ESLint

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, nestjs, eslint

I am using the below command for initializing a NestJS project with TypeScript:

```
nest new <project-name>
```

The issue here is, that an ESlint is also applied in the project with this command.

Is it possible to initialize without ESlint?